# PHP Foreach con Array dentro de Array

Tags: php, array

a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Estoy trabajando con foreach para capturar los datos de un Array y estoy teniendo problemas en algun caso concreto
Recojo el Array de forma dinamica, pero siempre tienen la misma estructura, como ejemplo

Array:

```
[{"valueX":"XXX","valueY":"YYY","valueZ":[{"Z1":"ZZZ1","Z2":"ZZZ2"}]}]
```

Siguiendo este ejemplo
Mediante un bucle foreach puedo capturar los datos de los valores "valueX" y "valueY", pero con consigo obtener los datos de valueZ ( que tiene su propio Array )

```
foreach ($Array as $v) {
        $mostrarvalorx = $v['valueX'];
        $mostrarvalory = $v['valueY'];
        $mostrarvalorz = $v['valueZ'];
}
```

Tras esto puedo hacer OK un `echo $mostrarvalorx;` y me muestra ok el dato.
De intentarlo con $mostrarvalorz el resultado es: Array
ok, es normal y si guardo el array en un archivo me lo muestra ok:

```
[{"Z1":"ZZZ1","Z2":"ZZZ2"}]
```

Sin embargo, con consigo captar los valores Z1 y Z2 dentro del foreach
He intentado hacerlo con:
$mostrarvalorz1 = sanear_string($v['valueZ']['Z1']);
Pero no me funciona, incluso si trato de guardar el resultado en un archivo este es "NULL"

Tambien he intentado algo como esto:

```
foreach($array as $datos =>$valores){
        
         echo "$datos ";
        
        foreach($valores as $datos2 => $resultado){
           
            echo "$datos : $resultado <br>";
           
     }
```

Pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, me muestra bien los valores del Array valueX y valueY, pero al mostrar valueZ lo sigue mostrando como un Array en lugar de mostrar los valores de Z1 y Z2

Gracias de antemano,
Un saludo

Editado
El Array original que me esta dando problemas es:

```
[
   {
      "eventid":"518368",
      "clock":"1615458857",
      "name":"Interface ether10(): Down",
      "severity":"1",
      "hosts":[
         {
            "hostid":"10485",
            "host":"10.100.0.1"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "eventid":"506073",
      "clock":"1615394237",
      "name":"Interface ether5(): Down",
      "severity":"1",
      "hosts":[
         {
            "hostid":"10485",
            "host":"10.100.0.1"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "eventid":"38030",
      "clock":"1606648937",
      "name":"ICMP Down",
      "severity":"1",
      "hosts":[
         {
            "hostid":"10485",
            "host":"10.100.0.1"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Es el dato "host" el que quiero guardar en una variable por cada una de las entradas que tenga el array.

Comment: qué es `sanear_string`? el comando `array_search` para lo que quieres hacer, no te sirve?

Comment: Gracias por responder
sanear_string lo utilizaba para limpiar la variable en el caso de que haya mas de una linea, aunque en este caso no se utiliza. Me sucede lo mismo sin eso.
Por lo que entiendo array_seach seria para buscar un valor dentro del Array, No, lo que necesito es captar el dato que tiene el campo Z2 del Array

Answer (score 0):

veamos según leo necesitas recorrer todo el array, tanto los elementos que son solo strings como el subarray. O sea necesitas iterar en profundidad.
En el primer código que pones *tratas a los tres items del array por igual, pero no son iguales*. El tercero es otro array, es diferente.

Sin embargo en el segundo ya te acercas a la solución.
Pero tal como está escrito vas a obtener más de un warning, observa que el bucle **foreach** interno lo aplicas a todos los items del array y en los dos primeros no tiene sentido (son cadenas no arrays).

Por lo tanto lo suyo sería comprobar si el item es un array o no. Si lo es pues iteras con el bucle.

Con los datos que das este código recorre el array completo y da todos los resultados. Lo he dejado para que muestre tanto la key (el indice dle array) como el valor.
Y para que veas como funciona lo he puesto con los echo, sin llamar a la función sanear_string()
Con mínimas modificaciones lo adaptas. A ver que te parece:

```
$array = ["valueX"=>"XXX","valueY"=>"YYY","valueZ"=>["Z1"=>"ZZZ1","Z2"=>"ZZZ2"]];  
foreach($array as $datos =>$valores){        
        if(is_array($valores)){  
            echo "$datos:  \n";  
            foreach($valores as $datos2 => $resultado){  
                echo "$datos2 : $resultado <br>";  
                }  
            }    
        else{  
            echo "$datos: $valores <br>";  
            }  
}
```

Si te vale esta solución y quieres usar la función de **sanear_string()** basta con cambiar los **echo** por **sanear_string($valores)**
Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: Hola Juan, 
Gracias por tu genial respuesta
Lo he estado probando y me funciona con el Array de prueba que dejé, pero no con el Array real que estoy trabajando, el echo me sigue printeando "Array" en lugar del valor. Creo que el problema puede venir de mi Array o como tratarlo
Añado una edicion en mi pregunta inicial, con el Array original que me esta dando problemas